# Testing a Wagtail StructBlock with a StreamBlockField

Tags: testing, wagtail

I'm attempting to run some unit tests on a StructBlock, which is composed of normal block fields and a StreamBlock.

The problem I'm running into is that I can construct a test that renders the block, but I cannot test the StreamBlock validation (i.e., I can't test the block's `clean()`)

**Stack**

- Python 3.9.6
- Django 3.2
- Wagtail 2.13
- pytest 6.2
- pytest-django 4.4

Block Definitions

**MyStructBlock**

```py
    class MyStructBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
        image = ImageChooserBlock()

        heading = blocks.CharBlock(required=True)
        description = blocks.RichTextBlock(features=["bold", "italic"])
        links = blocks.StreamBlock([("link", LinkBlock())], icon="link", min_num=1, max_num=6)

        class Meta:
            icon = "list-ul"
            template = "blocks/two_column_with_link_list_block.html"
```

**LinkBlock**

```py
    class LinkBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
        link_text = blocks.CharBlock()
        internal_link = blocks.PageChooserBlock()
        internal_document = DocumentChooserBlock()
        external_link = blocks.URLBlock()
```

With this setup I create this kind of `block_definition`:

```py
{
   'image': <Image: Thumbnail of subject>, 
   'heading': 'SomeText', 
   'description': 'Hello, Son', 
   'links':  
     [
       {'value': 
         {
          'link_text': 'Walk trip thought region.', 
          'internal_link': None, 
          'document_link': None, 
          'external_link': 'www.example.com'
         }
       },
       {'value': {...}},
       {'value': {...}},
      ]
}
```

Then a test like this will work just fine:

```py
   def test_structure():
      my_struct_block = MyStructBlock()
      block_def = block_definition
      rendered_block_html = BeautifulSoup(my_struct_block.render(value=block_def)))
      assert <<THINGS ABOUT THE STRUCTURE>>
```

The block renders and all is well, but when I try to `clean` the block everything starts to go sideways.

```py
   def test_validation():
       my_struct_block = MyStructBlock()
       block_def = block_definition
       rendered_block_html = BeautifulSoup(my_struct_block.render(my_struct_block.clean(block_def)))
```

Will result in something like this:

```py
self = <wagtail.core.blocks.field_block.RichTextBlock object at 0x7f874f430580>, value = 'Hello, Son'

    def value_for_form(self, value):
        # Rich text editors take the source-HTML string as input (and takes care
        # of expanding it for the purposes of the editor)
>       return value.source
E       AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'source'

.direnv/python-3.9.6/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wagtail/core/blocks/field_block.py:602: AttributeError
```

Which is descriptive enough -- I get that it requires a Richtext Block definition -- but why the difference?

**NOTE:** I have tried defining the `block_definition` using `RichText` as the value for fields that expect RichText, this fails. If I remove the `RichText` field, the clean proceeds to fail on the `dicts` I used to define the `LinkBlock`.

**Question**

Is there a canonical way to set up a test like this that can handle complex blocks, so that a common source of block definition can test `render` as well as `clean` and `render`? Or, does this type of block, in some way, require an integration approach where I construct a Page with the complex blocks added as `stream_data` and then request the Page and use the response's rendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every block type has a corresponding 'native' data type for the data it expects to work with - for the simpler blocks, this data type is what you'd expect (e.g. a string for CharBlock, an Image instance for ImageChooserBlock) but for a few of the more complex ones, there's a custom type defined:

- for RichTextBlock, the native type is `wagtail.core.rich_text.RichText` (which behaves similarly to a string, but also has a `source` property where e.g. page IDs in page links are kept intact)
- for StreamBlock, the native type is `wagtail.core.blocks.StreamValue` (a sequence type, where each item is a StreamValue with `block_type` and `value` properties).

The `render` method will generally be quite forgiving if you use the wrong types (such as a string for RichTextBlock or a list of dicts for StreamBlock), since it's really just invoking your own template code. The `clean` method will be more picky, since it's running Python logic specific to each block.

Unfortunately the correct types to use for each block aren't really formally documented, and some of them are quite fiddly to construct (e.g. a StructValue needs to be passed a reference to the corresponding StructBlock) - outside of test code, there isn't much need to create these objects from scratch, because the data will usually be coming from some outside source instead (e.g. a form submission or the database), and each block will be responsible for converting that to its native type.

With that in mind, I'd recommend that you construct your data by piggybacking on the `to_python` method, which converts the JSON representation as stored in the database (consisting of just simple Python data types - integers, strings, lists, dicts) into the native data types:

```
block_def = my_struct_block.to_python({
   'image': 123,  # the image ID
   'heading': 'SomeText', 
   'description': 'Hello, Son', 
   'links':  
     [
       {'type': 'link', 'value': 
         {
          'link_text': 'Walk trip thought region.', 
          'internal_link': None, 
          'document_link': None, 
          'external_link': 'www.example.com'
         }
       },
       {'type': 'link', 'value': {...}},
       {'type': 'link', 'value': {...}},
      ]
})
```

`my_struct_block.clean(block_def)` will hopefully then succeed.